# Activiti 6.0.0 and postgres database how to achieve multi tenancy using?

Tags: multi-tenant

How do I achieve multi tenancy using activiti 6.0.0 and postgres database? I want to design my own angular UI with activiti 6.0.0 as a base. This is where I want to achieve the multi tenancy where my tenant A, tenant B, and tenant N can access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2015/10/06/multi-tenancy-separate-database-schemas-in-activiti/ ? I'm guessing you've a specific domain/focus for your app and you've decided you don't need all the general-purpose features that the activiti 6 UI provides (especially modeling). In that case you might want to run the backend using spring boot (https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot) rather than the Activiti 6 WAR distribution that includes the general-purpose features and user interface. (I mention this because [activiti-rest](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/6.x/modules/activiti-rest) alone [doesn't include the API that backs the modeller used by the v6 Activiti UI](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/6.x/modules/activiti-ui/activiti-app-rest) - happy to discuss further if you've more questions.)

Comment: thanks for the information, but I want to build the custom app over the activiti v6 in ANGULAR JS not in java spring boot.. can you help me in that direction.

Comment: You could try adapting the AngularJS UI that comes with v6 (in the war package) - see https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/6.x/modules/activiti-ui/activiti-app/src/main/webapp Otherwise you can build a UI around the backend rest endpoints. The decisions you take about the backend will drive what those rest endpoints are.

Comment: thanks Ryan,after lots of discussion and RnD, we will go with the our custom spring boot application on top of activiti rest api as suggested (https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot)   and Custom UI for the app which will give us a in house support for activiti v6 rest . only thing I want to know is How to manage users for multiple tenants. I have gone thru the data model of activiti-app and didn't found the way to manage a users for multiple tenants. only process and models are managed.it will be great help if you can guide with example. 
thanks

Comment: In v6 the rest endpoint code for the user management is at https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/6.x/modules/activiti-ui/activiti-app-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/app/rest/idm You'll need to decide on your multi-tenant approach. Another article on this is https://www.techsophy.com/blog-multi-tenancy-activiti/ and you'll want to be aware of https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#advanced.tenancy and http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/05/24/how-to-extend-activiti-rest/ For a different direction see https://community.alfresco.com/thread/231987-activiti-6-identity-management-customization

Comment: Thanks Ryan, can I use ( github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/6.x/modules/activiti-ui/) code in my enterprise application.what should I need to to for same ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. It is open source so you are free to use it however you wish. You'll find most of the documentation is about using Activiti and adding your custom apps to it - you might not find as much documentation on extending it. If you're interested in future direction, the direction for Activiti 7 is towards using ADF for UI and multi-tenancy at platform level (e.g. Kubernetes).